# Customizing Buefy with SASS in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, sass, bulma, buefy

I'm a beginner at this and I'm struggling with changing style for buefy elements. In particular the buefy tabs.

In my component, I've got this style:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

// Import Bulma's core
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

// Set your own stuff
$my-primary: red;
$link: red;
$colors: (
  "primary": ($min-primary, $primary-invert)
);

$tabs-toggle-link-border-color: red;
$tabs-toggle-link-border-style: red;
$tabs-toggle-link-hover-background-color: red;
$tabs-toggle-link-hover-border-color: red;
$tabs-toggle-link-active-background-color: red;
$tabs-toggle-link-active-border-color:red;
$tabs-toggle-link-active-color: $link-invert !default;

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
</style>
```

And my tab is formatted like this:

```
<b-tabs type="is-toggle" size="is-medium" expanded>
```

The link color and the primary color are changed like expected. But the tabs remain in their original color.

There are two things I find strange:

1. If I move this styling to App.vue and remove the "scoped" - the styling does
   not work. However - the primary color and the link color changes to purple (not turquoise like I'd expected and which it does if I just remove the $colors from within the component). I thought all styling added to App.vue would work in all components?
2. Why does not the tabs change color? Have I got the wrong variables? How do I find the right variables? The variables used here is found in bulma/sass/components/tabs.sass.

Both node-sass and sass-loader are installed.

Hope somebody can make me feel a bit more enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** it turns out, there is a way how to get it working with `scoped` styles. For that all you need is to wrap `@import` statements into `/deep/` selector:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
... // everything else remains the same
/deep/ {
  // Import Bulma and Buefy styles
  @import "~bulma"; 
  @import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
}
```

**Original answer**

Even though this it's a bit old question, I faced the same problem recently with `dropdown` component.

Variables in original code are correct, but it does not work due to `scoped` styles. Since `@import` is called in `scoped` context, it will be also scoped and thus CSS will not match HTML.
Assuming that original code in `tab` component is something like this:

```
$tabs-border-bottom-color: $border !default
$tabs-border-bottom-style: solid !default
$tabs-border-bottom-width: 1px !default

.tabs
  @extend %block
  +overflow-touch
  @extend %unselectable
  align-items: stretch
  display: flex
  font-size: $size-normal
  justify-content: space-between
  overflow: hidden
  overflow-x: auto
  white-space: nowrap
  a
    align-items: center
    border-bottom-color: $tabs-border-bottom-color
    border-bottom-style: $tabs-border-bottom-style
    border-bottom-width: $tabs-border-bottom-width
....
```

After compiling Vue loader will add `[data-v-xxxxxxx]` so it will look:

```
.tabs[data-v-xxxxxx] {
// styles go here
}
```

but `html` for tabs is not scoped and this is the reason why it does not work.

One way to get it working would be to remove `scoped`, but wrap all your styles
into some class name to keep all css private for the component. Assuming that template root element has class `my-component-wrapper`, scss will be following:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.my-component-wrapper {
  // Import Bulma's core
  @import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

  // Set your own stuff
  $my-primary: red;
  $link: red;
  $colors: (
    "primary": ($min-primary, $primary-invert)
  );

  $tabs-toggle-link-border-color: red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-border-style: red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-hover-background-color: red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-hover-border-color: red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-active-background-color: red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-active-border-color:red;
  $tabs-toggle-link-active-color: $link-invert !default;

  // Import Bulma and Buefy styles
  @import "~bulma";
  @import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
}
</style>
```

Worth noting that you do not have to import `bulma` and `buefy` for each component, it's better to import main/general styles in main file and then import only necessary components (`@import "~bulma/sass/components/tabs";`).